BigQuery Table Wildcard (_*) and UNNEST() with _TABLE_SUFFIX - "does not have a schema" error
I have a table with the following schema, auto-partitioned by the ingestion date:
mytable_YYYYMMDD



Field name
Type
Mode




field1
BOOLEAN
NULLABLE


field2
RECORD
REPEATED



I am trying to schedule a query for the nested items under field2, a daily data dump into a separate BigQuery table new_table. For example:
SELECT
*
FROM `my-project.my_dataset.mytable_*`, UNNEST(field2)
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', CURRENT_DATE())

The question I have is that the above code returns the BigQuery UI error:

Table my-project.my_dataset.mytable_* does not have a schema.

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing / why is the UI giving me this schema error, when it clearly exists?

Perhaps it's because today's shard of your table has not been created yet. If you are working with a GA4 table, this is common. Test this filter instead and check for errors. WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', CURRENT_DATE() - 2) a
